# Is there a mathematical function with a shape like an inverted sigmoid pdf but X values that go beyond 1?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I am looking for a mathematical function that can produce a shape like the one below:

[image]

The above curve has probabilities ranging between 0 and 1, with the x values being able to take any positive integer. The actual values of X or where the distribution curves don't matter so much (although the ability to define these is necessary).

Is there a function that produces that can take a shape similar to this one?

Comment: Because your sketch isn't remotely like any PDF -- it integrates approximately to 75 (or more), not 1 -- and because you state the support of the distribution is integral, which means it doesn't have a pdf -- it is hard to know what you're trying to ask.  Could you provide some context or clarification?

Comment: An appropriately rescaled beta distribution may do the trick, see this beta(0.5,2) on the log scale: https://imgur.com/a/ofncVcd

Comment: Apologies - you are right! I am editing for clarity now, but essentially I am looking for a mathematical function that can produce a shape like the plot above.

Comment: The height of a PDF represents probability *density*, not probability, and is not in general limited to [0, 1]. For a given shape of the PDF curve, the scale of the y-axis is whatever is needed to make the curve integrate to 1.

Comment: All good points - apologies for my mistake. I have amended the question to reflect this.

Comment: What is the intended behavior at x=0 and x=150?  The way you have drawn them it looks like a vertical asymptote, but your description suggests that you mean for the curve to be bounded.  It might help if you describe what you are trying to model and why you expect it to have a shape like this.

Comment: I am creating a virtual species that has a response like that above to an environmental gradient. At X = 0, P(X) = 1, and at X = 150,  P(X) = 0. In saying that, I am really just after a clear mathematical formula for producing a curve like the one above where I can control where it curves -> the actual probabilities could just be re-scaled between those boundaries though.

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants a distribution function, but most people seem to be reading this as a request for a density function, as I did before seeing the answer. PDF = probability density function.

Comment: @NickCox But it's decreasing.

Comment: Sure. What is a complement between friends? Various names: I have seen complementary, converse or reverse distribution function, reliability function, survival function or survivor function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A one-parameter family of functions that seems to do what you want is one minus the quantile function of the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), up to rescaling $x$ by dividing by 150. "One-parameter", because setting both parameters of the beta to the same value ensures symmetry. You want this parameter to be (quite a bit) larger than one.

[image: function]

In R:

```
xx <- seq(0,150)
parameter <- 100
plot(xx,1-qbeta(xx/150,parameter,parameter),type="l")
```

Comment: Isn't this one minus the *quantile* function of a rescaled beta distribution?  To have it as one minus the CDF (i.e. the survival function), I would think that you might want `parameter` close to $0$ as in something like `curve(1-pbeta(x/150,0.05,0.05),from=0,to=150)`

Comment: @Henry: thank you, good catch, I edited.